# One step of proving Kolmogorov's Inequality

Tags: probability-theory

I am stuck on one step of proving Kolmogorov's Inequality.

Let $\{X_{n}\}$ be a sequence of independent random variables with mean zero and finite variance. Let $S_{n}=\sum_{j=1}^{n}X_{j}$

Define $\Lambda=\{\omega: \max_{1\leq k \leq n}|S_{k}|\geq \epsilon\}$. Define $\Lambda_{k}=\{\omega: \max_{1\leq j \leq k-1}|S_{j}|<\epsilon, |S_{k}|\geq \epsilon\}$

Now I've proved $\Lambda_{k}$ are disjoint and $S_{n}-S_{k}$ are independent of $S_{k}$. Now I want to prove $$\int_{\Lambda_{k}}S_{n}^{2}dP \geq \int_{\Lambda_{k}}S_{k}^{2}dP$$

I know I can write $S_{n}=S_{k}+(S_{n}-S_{k})$, but I don't know how to prove $S_{k}$ and $S_{n}-S_{k}$ are indepedent on $\Lambda_{k}$ formally. Could someone help me with it/

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Define the probability measure $Q$ (on whatever $\sigma$-algebra you started with) by $Q(E) = P(\Lambda_k \cap E)/P(\Lambda_k)$. We'd like to show, for any $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$, that

$$ Q( \{ S_k < a \} \cap \{ S_n - S_k < b \}) = Q(\{ S_k < a \}) Q(\{ S_n - S_k < b \}), $$

i.e.

$$ \frac{P(\Lambda_k \cap \{ S_k < a \} \cap \{ S_n - S_k < b \})}{P(\Lambda_k)} = \frac{P(\Lambda_k \cap \{ S_k < a \}) P(\Lambda_k \cap \{ S_n - S_k < b \})}{P(\Lambda_k)^2}    $$

But $\Lambda_k, \{ S_k < a \} \in \sigma(X_1, \dots, X_k)$, the $\sigma$-algebra generated by $X_1, \dots, X_k$, while $\{ S_n - S_k < b \} \in \sigma(X_{k+1}, \dots, X_n)$. These $\sigma$-algebras are independent. To finish, rewrite $P(\Lambda_k \cap \{ S_n - S_k < b \})$, and follow your nose.